# How can i get pie chart with dynamic json data in Angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, charts, highcharts

in my controller:

calling the web services if the services is success then get the data and pushinig the data into corresponding arrays

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.reportRangeList.length; i++)
{                           
     count++;

    if(angular.isNumber($scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName))
    {
        $scope.nameBusiness.push($scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName);
    }else{                                  
        $scope.nameBusiness.push(+$scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName);
        }
    if(angular.isNumber($scope.reportRangeList[i].total1))
    {
        $scope.total.push($scope.reportRangeList[i].total1);
    }else{
        $scope.total.push(+$scope.reportRangeList[i].total1);
    }

    if(count == $scope.reportRangeList.length){
    //$log.info("dddd"+ angular.toJson($scope.bname) )
    $scope.fetchChart();
    $scope.comlete = true;
    }
}
```

and in fetchChart() :

```
$scope.fetchChart = function(){
   $scope.chartConfig = {
    title: {
      text: ""
    },tooltip: {
     visible: true,
     pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
    },
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      },
    plotOptions: {
       series: {
        stacking: ''
       },
      pie: {
     allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
    style: {
    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
    }
  },
 showInLegend: true
  },
},
legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'topleft',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 1,
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
    }
    },

    /*xAxis: {
   categories: $scope.bname
    },*/
    credits: {
    enabled: true
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
     labels: {
     template:'{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
      position: "outsideEnd",
     visible: true,
     background: "transparent"
    }
    },
    series: [{
    type: "pie",
    name: "",
     data: //$scope.bname,
        [
        $scope.nameBusiness,$scope.total
         //['Firefox', 42.0]
          /* ['IE', 26.8],
       {
           name: 'Chrome',
          y: 14.8,
          sliced: true,
         selected: true
      },
        ['Safari', 6.5],
      ['Opera', 8.2],
     ['Others', 0.7]*/
    ],
}],
           loading: false
     }
       };
```

I would like to display the pie chart high chart with above data ,in for loop i am try to push only numbers but it shows single line of pie chart even the circle is not formed .with out converting to number type when I was  push ,it shows http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14 error .One more thing I can share `$scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName` is string type and `$scope.reportRangeList[i].total1` is number type .
 The pie chart is working with hard coded data .Now how can I get pie chart with dynamic json data .

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan could you please answer this question .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `businessName` is string, and your data format expects to be number. I guess you have pairs `businessName` + `total1` for each slice, that's correct? In that case, create one point for each of pairs:

```
series: [{
    type: "pie",
    name: "",
    data: [
        [ $scope.nameBusiness, $scope.total ] // [name, value] format
    ]
 }],
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ,but the series type of your suggestion is not working for me ,and please read my question it was updated .

Comment: I didn't change your series type, just show you how data should be passed to the series... just read my answer and try it.

Comment: Fus,Thank you for your replay ,I made changes in controller.
The for loop :
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.reportRangeList.length; i++)
{
 count++; 

 arr.push($scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName  , $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1);
 alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
for this i got the out put like:[
    "abc",1820,
    "pqrs",2349.67

 ]
Now i have to get output like :[
    "abc",1820
],

 [    "pqrs",2349.67

 ]
Then it is working the pie chart displays data.Can u guide me how to convert the output like that.

Comment: There should be: `arr.push([$scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName , $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1]);`

Answer (score 0):

As I'm working on angular 2, I'll provide solution related to it.. See if it can help you..

1. Firstly, create a function and call the service which will fetch
   result from the server and store the result in a variable.
2. Then use that variable in data section of your graph in place of static data.

Hope it will solve your issue.